# Is this method of component communication an Ember anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application

Take this html and JS:

```html
{{#main-view}}
  <!-- page html - header, content, etc. -->

  {{some-action tagName='button'}} Do it

  <!-- more page html -->

{{/main-view}}
```

```js
// components/main-view.js

Ember.Component.extend({
  mainView: true,
  doSomething: function() { alert('doing something') }
})

// components/some-action.js

Ember.Component.extend({
  mainView: null,

  configureMainView: function() {
    this.set('mainView', this.nearestWithProperty('mainView');
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  click: function() {
    this.get('mainView').doSomething(); 
  }
})
```

The idea so to have descendent components be able to interact with the interfaces of ancestors. A use case example could be you want the individual page content containers to be able to configure whether or not a hamburger menu is available on the page, like `{{page-content show-menu='false'}}`. This way you can simply define the menu at the top level and let children configure it as they need for their content.

I'm coming from the angular world, but it seems the more preferred way to handle this kind of thing in Ember is to bind to controller properties or handle actions in routes/controller actions at any appropriate level in the action bubbling. I can't help but feel that in many cases the controllers and routes have no business worrying about UI configurations, and so the related UI components should be able to simply communicate with each other and leave the controllers out of it.

Another pattern I've actually seen in `ember-cli` addons has been for children components to lookup and register themselves with a specific parent. And then the parent will call the interfaces of the children, or manipulate them however they see fit. Basically the same concept as above, just the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ember way' to communicate would be add an action handler to the component from the parent template:

// components/main-view.js

```
{{#main-view}}
  <!-- page html - header, content, etc. -->

  {{some-action tagName='button' action="doSomething"}} Do it

  <!-- more page html -->

{{/main-view}}
```

// components/some-action.js

```
Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function() {
    this.sendAction();
  }
});
```

if you don't want to handle it on the parent, just let it bubble up.
It goes over this in the guide: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/

Comment: So when the `some-action` isn't in the same context/scope as the `main-view` (and therefore can't directly send the action to it), you'd have to define an action on a route higher up and then observe a controller property from `main-view` to know when the action has been taken?

Comment: Can you give me an example of where you would want two components, that aren't in the same hierarchy, interacting without some kind of third party object?